# How to enable SSL certificate validation on SSLSocket created using SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure

Tags: java, android, ssl, sni, sslsocketfactory

I am trying to create SSLSocket with the following properties:

1. it should do SSL certificate validation.
2. it should allow to set custom SNI (server name indication).

From what I have understood:

1. `SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getDefault` does not do allow you to set custom SNI and but does SSL cert validation.
2. `SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure` does allow you to set custom SNI and but does not do SSL cert validation.

So the best possible solution could be to enable SSL cert validation on SSLSocket created using `SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure`.

I am using the following code to set custom SNI:

```
SSLCertificateSocketFactory ssf = (SSLCertificateSocketFactory) SSLCertificateSocketFactory
        .getInsecure(Utils.getConnectTimeOutForHost(m_host),
                null);
m_sslsocket = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(m_socket, m_host,
        m_port, false);
m_sslsocket.setEnabledProtocols(m_sslsocket.getSupportedProtocols());

String hostName = getSNIHost();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Setting SNI hostname");
    ssf.setHostname(m_sslsocket, hostName);
} else {
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Method setHostnameMethod = m_sslsocket
                .getClass().getMethod("setHostname", String.class);
        setHostnameMethod.invoke(m_sslsocket, hostName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "SNI not useable", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? Why not start with a secure factory?

Comment: Are you referring to SSLSocketFactory? How would you set SNI in that case?